# Writing an algorithm that solves all possible combinations of given numbers for a solution

Tags: java, algorithm, list

The idea for this is that there is a list of numbers that can be used more than once (if the solution is 5 and the list is (1, 4, 2) then possible solutions are (1,1,1,1,1)   (1,4)    (1,2,2)    (4,1)   (2,1,1,1)   (2,1,2)    (2,2,1)

my current code is :

```
static void J5(int distance, ArrayList<Integer> p)
{
    for (int i=0; i < p.size(); i++)
    {
        int sub = (distance - p.get(i));

        if (sub == 0)
        {
            System.out.print(p.get(i) + "\n");
            return;
        }
        if (sub < 0)
        {
            sub = distance - p.get(i);      
        }
        if (sub > 0)
        {
            System.out.print(p.get(i) + " ");
            J5(sub, p);
        }
    }
}
```

so essentially it is taking the subtraction from the distance of 5 and using recursion on the outcome. my output is

```
2 2 1
1 2
4 1
1 2 2
4
```

So pretty much the only fully correct one in this instance is the first iteration as 2 + 2 + 1 = 5, but then the next one should be something like (2,1,2) 
all while there also isn't a (1,1,1,1,1) even though each element can be used multiple times.

Comment: You should introduce a new variable, and store current answer there during the recursion, then print it in `sub == 0`.

Comment: what do you mean by current answer? wouldn't it just get lost anyways once the recursion is called?

Comment: So pass it to the recursion - add a new argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here I wrote a neat and clean solution for you:

```
public class Test {
    static void combinationSumUtils(int indx, int sum, ArrayList<Integer> candidates, ArrayList<Integer> solution) {
        if(indx == candidates.size()) {
            if(sum == 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i) {
                    System.out.print(solution.get(i) + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            return;
        }
        if(sum == 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < solution.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.print(solution.get(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < candidates.size(); ++i) {
            if(sum - candidates.get(i) >= 0) {
                solution.add(candidates.get(i));
                combinationSumUtils(i, sum - candidates.get(i), candidates, solution);
                solution.remove(solution.size() - 1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> candidates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        candidates.add(1);
        candidates.add(4);
        candidates.add(2);
        Collections.sort(candidates);
        combinationSumUtils(0, 5, candidates, solution);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 2 
1 1 2 1 
1 2 1 1 
1 2 2 
1 4 
2 1 1 1 
2 1 2 
2 2 1 
4 1
```

Equivalent C++ solution:

```
void combinationSumUtils(int indx, int sum, vector<int> &candidates, vector<int> &solution, vector<vector<int> > &result) {
        if(indx == candidates.size()) {
            if(sum == 0) result.push_back(solution);
            return;
        }
        if(sum == 0) {
            result.push_back(solution);
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < candidates.size(); ++i) {
            if(sum - candidates[i] >= 0) {
                solution.push_back(candidates[i]);
                combinationSumUtils(i, sum - candidates[i], candidates, solution, result);
                solution.pop_back();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<vector<int> > combinationSum(vector<int> &candidates, int target) {
        vector<vector<int> > result;
        vector<int> solution;
        if(candidates.size() < 0) return result;
        sort(candidates.begin(), candidates.end());
        combinationSumUtils(0, target, candidates, solution, result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: That's great, but unfortunately you've used the wrong language.

Comment: Ops! I updated my answer with Java solution. Thank you :)

Comment: funny. The coding-service gets upvotes, the solution that finds the bugs gets ignored...

Comment: I didn't see your answer, I appreciate your answer more than my answer and I gave an up-vote already. I found the code in the question little messy and unorganised, thats why I planned to provide a precise and clean snippet. You pointed out the bug in his code which will more beneficial for him obviously. I think your answer should be accepted :)

Comment: @KaidulIslam thanks. Just thought the behaviour was a bit odd.

Answer (score 1):

The code actually works. You just misinterpreted it. Just add a bit of structure to the output and you'll notice it:

```
static void J5(int distance, String indent , ArrayList<Integer> p)
{
    for(int i=0; i < p.size();i++)
    {
        int sub = (distance - p.get(i));

        if (sub == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(indent + p.get(i)+ " Solution found" + "\n");

            return;
        }else if (sub > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(indent + p.get(i)+ " " + " distance remaining: " + sub);
            J5(sub , indent + "\t" , p);
        }
    }
}
```

And the produced output would be:

```
1  distance remaining: 4
    1  distance remaining: 3
        1  distance remaining: 2
            1  distance remaining: 1
                1 Solution found

            2 Solution found

        2  distance remaining: 1
            1 Solution found //Note: the complete sequence would be 1 1 2 1

    2  distance remaining: 2
        1  distance remaining: 1
            1 Solution found

        2 Solution found

    4 Solution found

2  distance remaining: 3
    1  distance remaining: 2
        1  distance remaining: 1
            1 Solution found

        2 Solution found

    2  distance remaining: 1
        1 Solution found

4  distance remaining: 1
    1 Solution found
```

Just look at it as a kind of tree. The indent is shows the recursion-depth, which is equivalent to the level of each node. An entire path contains the complete solution. Each "Solution-found" would be equivalent to a new-line in the sample-output of your code.

The algorithm works just fine. It just doesn't print the entire set of found numbers whenever a valid solution is found.

A few notes on the code itself: the second `if`-clause in your code is useless. The modification made to `sub` is thrown away without ever being used and there are no other modifications in it. And this algorithm requires a **sorted** list as input, you'll have to take that into account if you want to use this code.

As for the solution itself: simply keep the so far generated solution as a parameter to the next call:

```
void J5(int distance , ArrayList<Integer> p , String solution){
    ...
    if(sub == 0){
        System.out.println(solution + " " + p.get(i));
    }else if(sub > 0){
        J5(sub , p , solution + p.get(i));
    }
}
```

And as for the missing "1 1 1 1 1"-output: worked just fine for me.